# Calling c_str of empty string

Tags: c++

Is this code fragment OK or does it result in undefined behavior?

```
std::string s;
assert(strlen(s.c_str())==0);
```

If it isn't undefined behavior, will the above assertion pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will work (if you append `()` to `c_str` to make it actually call the function) and the assertion will pass.

Answer (score 13):

That is perfectly well defined and the assertion passes. The c_str() function will always return a valid zero terminated C string.

One would normally use empty() to test for an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

It's a compile error (if you have assertions enabled), since a `const char *(std::string::*)()`, cannot be converted to `const char *` implicitly.

(Tongue only halfway in cheek.)